# Assembly, Namespace, DAL; What classes belongs where?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, data-access-layer

I would like to understand a few basics about Assemblies and Namespaces. I've reproduced an NHibernate tutorial, and everything works fine. But I'm not sure if I agree on what classes go where. So look at Solution Explorer image attached..

**Domain** and **Repositories** (with classes in folders) are **namespaces**. And here both are in the ...DAL assembly.

1. Is there any logical reason to put it there? **Product** is a **POCO** class. Shouldn't that more naturally belong outside the DAL assembly?
2. Is it correct to put **IProductRepository** in the **Domain** namespace? And if you suggest to move the POCO classes, would you also move the IProductRepository?
3. What would I need to do if I wanted to make the **DAL** usable by **both C# and VB.NET** projects?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any logical reason to put it
>   there? Product is a POCO class.
>   Shouldn't that more naturally belong
>   outside the DAL assembly?

The argument for putting the POCO class in with the persistence implementation is to simplify deployment and reduce the total number of needed assemblies.

That is not to say I agree with the practice.

It is a better practice, and perhaps even more conventional, to place the *definitions* of the domain objects in one assembly, and the implementations that depend on the persistence technology in another.

Clients can then reference the assembly of domain object definitions without being tied to the implementation strategy.

> Is it correct to put
>   IProductRepository in the Domain
>   namespace? And if you suggest to move
>   the POCO classes, would you also move
>   the IProductRepository?

Yes, it is correct for the definition of a Repository to be in the Domain.

Repositories are a domain concept, they are not generic - at least not the interface they expose (the implementations may in fact be generic).

The interfaces for the Repository should live with the definitions for the Entities (whether they are POCO's or just interfaces) and with all other domain objects.

> What would I need to do if I wanted to
>   make the DAL usable by both C# and
>   VB.NET projects?

Nothing special.  You can reference the assembly from either C# or VB.Net, whether the DAL and/or Domain assemblies were written in C# or VB.Net.  This is a large advantage of .Net as a whole and is quite intentional and by design.

Comment: I can't understand the attraction to **physically** partitioning domain and repository classes by creating separate assemblies, except in a few marginal scenarios; what are the benefits? Even with a single assembly, clients are welcome to reference the domain object definitions without being compelled to use specific implementation strategies. Nonetheless, you've fairly presented the case for the single-assembly approach, so +1 (Patrick Smacchia goes into more detail [in an article here](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/12/08/advices-on-partitioning-code-through-net-assemblies/)).

Comment: @Jeff: it is not to partition the domain and repository classes.  That is not the point.  It is to partition the classes that must reference the persistence technology from the interfaces and classes that comprise the definition of the domain (and have no need or purpose referencing the persistence technology).

Comment: It's a point of preference, imo, and somewhat inconsequential on small teams.  But on larger, looser, or distributed teams having that separation can prevent other developers from inadvertantly violating project guidelines by taking a dependency on the persistence technology in an inappropriate place, just because they can (and so don't know better).

Comment: Thanks!! One thing is unclear for me: If POCOs rest in a DAL assembly, I believe will deny any outside assembly to extend them. How to make possible; for a project to put some behavior in those "POCOs"? Can they still be inherited across assemblies? Or alternatively; Could one have both definitions AND implementations of the POCOs in the DAL assembly, and then allow each project chose either to use that implementation, or have their own implementation? In such case, what type would I then pass between DAL assembly and project assembly?

Comment: You can inherit classes from another project as long as the class itself and at least one of its constructors is accessible (not internal). But these classes were talking about are your business objects or domain objects, no?  If so, it seems to make no sense whatsoever to have alternate implementations.  Also, no, you cannot cast from one implementation (class) to another, unless such a type conversion is specifically implemented.  You can hold a reference to either implementation with a reference to the interface they both share, but not convert from one implementing class to another.

Comment: Yes they are business objects. My current "habit" is to have quite a lot of logic/behavior inside these classes. So I wonder now if I have POCOs in the DAL, if I need to change that approach, to put the behavior elsewhere?  (I only worked with in-memory objects and serialization to file before, so not used to having assembly separation on the data access side.)

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would put the POCOs in their own library, something like MyProject.Model or "Domain" as you call it.  The reason being is that I might want to use them outside of the DAL as well, somewhere higher on the food chain without referencing the DAL assembly.  For example I might front the .DataAccess with a .Business project, which will return the same .Model (Domain) objects.  Typically my repositories live in MyProject.DataAccess.Repositories for example.  You should be able to reference a .NET assembly (no matter if it's C# or VB.NET) from any project without any problems.